# C# data extracting from the file into byte array

Tags: c#, stream, byte

Can anyone explain me about the following code what it is doing and
why it is substracting the size by 44.

```
public byte[] recorded_file = new byte[1000000];
public bool recorded_first_stream;
public int recorded_file_location;  

public async void TestFile(object object_name)
{
string file_name = (string)object_name;
string full_file_name = System.IO.Path.Combine
                             (Properties.Settings.Default.wave_files_location, file_name);
if (File.Exists(full_file_name))
{
            // WaveStream fileStream = new AudioFileReader(full_file_name);

            recorded_first_stream = true;
            FileStream fs = File.Open(full_file_name, FileMode.Open,
                                                FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            recorded_file_location = (int)new System.IO.FileInfo(full_file_name).Length - 44;
            BinaryReader wave_file = new BinaryReader(fs);
            wave_file.BaseStream.Seek(44, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] wave_bytes = wave_file.ReadBytes(1000000);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(wave_bytes, 0, recorded_file, 0, wave_bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: The `Seek` offset from Begin is 44. I don't know wav file format, but maybe the first 44 bytes are insignificant for the task.

Comment: wave file is a .wav audio file

Comment: I know that, I mean I do not know the details of the binary format or what might be in the first 44 bytes.

Comment: I was going through the wav format I just got some answer . First 44 byte consists of file header like rate,format,size,id etc . so they removed .  Thank you for asking about the file format .